# Releasing synthesized property after alloc init

Tags: objective-c

i have a property

```
//.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeCLass * someSynthInstance;
//.m
@synthesize someSynthInstance = _someSynthInstance;

- (void) foo 
{
    self.someSynthInstance = [[SomeCLass alloc] init];
    //[self.someSynthInstance release]; <- SHOULD I RELEASE HERE???
}

- (void) dealloc 
{
    self.someSynthInstance = nil;
}
```

my theory goes, that [alloc, init] creates a count of 1, and the setter, inc that count, so it becomes 2, therefore i should release it, right after

but aim getting exc_bad_access in the application after i changed everything like this, so aim not sure if its ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to be releasing the instance variable rather than the property. so you can do either:

```
self.someSynthInstance = [[[SomeCLass alloc] init] autorelease]; // puts it in the autoreleasepool so it'll get released automatically at some point in the near future
```

or

```
_someSynthInstance = [[SomeCLass alloc] init]; // skip the property
```

or

```
self.someSynthInstance = [[SomeCLass alloc] init];
[_someSynthInstance release]; // call release on the instance variable
```

Comment: i used the autorelease pattern, that did it - the problem was, that i thought when calling [self.someSynthInstance release] that iam releasing _somSynthInstance, but it actually did release my property itself...

Comment: a fourth option is SomeClass *tmpObj = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
self.someSynthInstance = tmpObj;
[tmpObj release];

Answer (score 3):

The standard practice is:

```
SomeClass *tmpObj = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
self.someSynthInstance = tmpObj;
[tmpObj release];
```

Answer (score 2):

you should release the class variable instead.. like `[_someSynthInstance release];` that should do the trick.

Comment: that will bring the retain count by -1, still retain count will be 1 cos of self.variable assignment of retain property.

Comment: see  the selected correct answer , even he has done the same thing.

Comment: you are correct about selected answer but the problem is there as well.

Answer (score 1):

yes you should release after init

```
SomeCLass *temp = [[SomeCLass alloc] init];
self.someSynthInstance = temp;
[temp release]
```